# Handle response headers after cordovaFileTransfer

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I use `cordovaFileTransfer` for image upload in my `ionic` app. Also i use `ng-token-auth` for authorization. It exchanging tokens with devise through headers.
Problem is that `ng-token-auth` intercepting `http` service where tokens are updated, however cordova does not use `http` service.

So how is possible to handle reponse after file upload to update tokens that are in headers.

Updated.
Here i call file upload.

```
@cordovaFileTransfer.upload(
  upload_path,
  file_uri,
  httpMethod: method,
  headers:  @auth.retrieveData('auth_headers')
 )
```

Here is ng-token-auth code which intercepts http:

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push([
  '$injector', function($injector) {
    return {
      request: function(req) {
        $injector.invoke([
          '$http', '$auth', function($http, $auth) {
            var key, val, _ref, _results;
            if (req.url.match($auth.apiUrl())) {
              _ref = $auth.retrieveData('auth_headers');
              _results = [];
              for (key in _ref) {
                val = _ref[key];
                _results.push(req.headers[key] = val);
              }
              console.log("REQUEST_NEW_HEADERS")
              console.log(req)
              console.log($auth.retrieveData('auth_headers'))
              console.log(_results)

              return _results;
            }
          }
        ]);
        return req;
      },
      response: function(resp) {
        $injector.invoke([
          '$http', '$auth', function($http, $auth) {
            if (resp.config.url.match($auth.apiUrl())) {
              console.log('[RESP_SUCCESS]')
              console.log(resp.headers())
              return updateHeadersFromResponse($auth, resp);
            }
          }
        ]);
        return resp;
      },
      responseError: function(resp) {
        $injector.invoke([
          '$http', '$auth', function($http, $auth) {
            if (resp.config.url.match($auth.apiUrl())) {
              console.log('[RESP_ERROR]')
              console.log(resp.headers())

              return updateHeadersFromResponse($auth, resp);
            }
          }
        ]);
        return $injector.get('$q').reject(resp);
      }
    };
  }
]);
```

Comment: can you provide some code

Comment: At this moment i just does not create new token after file is uploaded.